# How do I test for attribute is Null in Drools 5

Tags: drools, rules, mvel

Drools 5, dialect mvel

I would like this rule to match only when any MappingFile object is present and only when the BLuReport object with the Reason code is NULL

How can I write that comparison expression... I tried several things without success:

```
rule "Mapping.Control Group to BlueReport"
    when 
        $internalAccount : MappingFile( $mappingControlGroup : controlGroup )
        $blueReport : BlueReport( **$Reason is null**  : Reason )
    then
        System.out.println("Updating BlueReport.controlGroup from MappingFile.controlGroup" + " Rule=" + drools.getRule().getName());
        modify ( $blueReport ) {
            setControl_group( $mappingControlGroup ),
            setReason( "Found mapping in the Internal Account object with account_id=" + $internalAccount.getExternalKey() );
        }
        retract ( $blueReport )
    end
```

Also, I had to add retract ( BR) because I kept getting an infinite loop after the update... am I doing the update correctly?!

Answer (score 0):

If the `BlueReport` field is really named `Reason` (contrary to Java naming conventions) then you simply write:

```
rule "Mapping.Control Group to BlueReport"
when 
    $internalAccount : MappingFile( $mappingControlGroup : controlGroup )
    $blueReport : BlueReport( Reason == null ) # or reason?
then
    System.out.println("Updating BlueReport.controlGroup from MappingFile.controlGroup" + " Rule=" + drools.getRule().getName());
    modify ( $blueReport ) {
        setControl_group( $mappingControlGroup ),
        setReason( "Found mapping in the Internal Account object with account_id=" + $internalAccount.getExternalKey() );
    }
    retract ( $blueReport );
end
```

Perhaps you should also have a constraint `control_group != $mappingControlGroup`.

Using either of these constraints will also avoid looping.